# I have a retracted article for ethical misconduct, this means my career is over?

Tags: publishing, technical-writing, academic-writing, plagiarism, ethics

When I was in my first year of M.SC. A professor told me to work on a project that the main data were belong to him. He had sent me a early draft and told me to translate it to english so I did along with recalculations and adding some stuff to paper. We have sent the article to a journal and got published there. But a year later the journal contact me because of a duplication base on a conference proceeding with the professor name and another student which was for 3 years before this. 
As off this moment the journal retracted the article, they didnt charge me guilty at all in my university but they fired the prof because he had multiple other misconducts before that. 
Is this end of my academic career? 
I am trying to apply for phd, does this means no one ever gonna accept me? 
What should I do? 
Im really overthinking this, I am really scared that no where accepts me for future studies. 
What should I do when I was not even guilty but yet there have been a retraction based on this issue?

Comment: Hi Jam B! I feel that other sites like academia.stackexchange.com or workplace.stackexchange.com may be a better fit for this question.

Comment: This is way outside my expertise, but I would ask your university to acquire a letter of apology to you from the professor, stating clearly that you were, at the time of publication, unaware of any misconduct associated with the research.  If the professor will not provide such a letter, in response to the university's official request, then have the university craft a letter, signed by the university's senior staff and the appropriate department head, absolving you of guilt on the matter of the misconduct.  Armed with either letter, you should be okay.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in Academia.SE

Comment: Hi Jam. I'm going to migrate this to [academia.se], our sister site for questions about higher education. I encourage you to follow your question there and to register an account so you can interact properly with the question you have asked. See https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/why-register and https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/creating-accounts.

Comment: The migration was rejected because this had already been posted at https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/114254/5856. Jam, please don't post the same question to multiple sites in the network; doing so just increases the workload for everyone involved.

Comment: I think you need some **official** paper from your university. So, it should be official paper with all **stamps and signatures from the chief university administration**. In this paper it should be stated that this is not your fault. To be honest, it doesn't look very hard.